# Expanding/Collapsing All The Master Rows devepress mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am using this link http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/MasterDetail/MasterDetail to devolp master and details grid. 
Now I want to expanding/collapsing all the master rows when click on button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the [ASPxClientGridView.CollapseAllDetailRows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_CollapseAllDetailRowstopic) and [ASPxClientGridView.ExpandAllDetailRows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_ExpandAllDetailRowstopic) client side methods

You can follow the example posted [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q345800)

(Make sure you use the GridView Name properly in your client side call)